# clicking on a button is working only with debugger

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a button that i'm trying to click on it,
when i'm running the test normally he is not being "clicked"
when i'm running the test with debugger everything works fine

I set `implicitlyWait` of 30 seconds and even if I change it doesn't make any difference,
my problem is when i'm clicking on the "Next" button

this is the site code:

```
<div class="b24-network-auth-form-btn-block">
    <input style="display: none;" name="login" value="user">
    **<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-md ui-btn-success ui-btn-round b24-network-auth-form-btn" data-action="submit">Next</button>**
    <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-md ui-btn-light ui-btn-round b24-network-auth-form-btn" data-action="forgot">Forgot password?</button>
</div>
```

and this is my test:

```
public class LoginPage extends Base
{           
   @FindBy(id="login")      
   public WebElement txtUserName; //user name
   @FindBy(xpath="/html//div[@id='authorize-layout']/div/div[3]//form//button[.='Next']")
   public WebElement btnNext; //"next" button
   @FindBy(id="password")
   public WebElement txtPassword;   //password

  public void login(String sUser, String sPass) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
  {
        Update.text(txtUserName,"User Name",sUser);         //type the user name
        Click.click(btnNext, "Next button");                //click the "next" button
        Update.text(txtPassword, "Password", sPass);        //type the "password" button
        Click.click(btnNext, "Next button");                //click the "next" button
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with Thread.sleep once to find to out if its a wait issue?

Comment: I tried to add the sleep, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means there is wait issue.

Put some wait like:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.""""""));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.""""""));
```

Put your By locator of button in above code